# Why is this question a duplicate?

Tags: discussion

I would like to understand why [this question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/556484/inversion-in-relative-clause) was classified as a duplicate. Is it not a bit stretched? I can see the similarity, but the structures present in the body of each question are in fact different:

> on which grazed a few cattle and sheep (where the predicate ***graze*** precedes the subject without the dummy preliminary subject "there")

and

> In a hole in the ground there lived a hobbit (where the structure is ***there + verb + subject***).

It is true that the first structure does get attention in the other question later in the answers and comments, but still, I don't see why two questions about different structures were treated as duplicates. What am I missing, can someone help me understand the principle?

Comment: The question should probably be closed for other reasons, such as lack of research or moved  to ELL.

Answer (score 2):

Because I believe that fixating on the expletive *there* mistakes the forest for the trees.  Pretending that 1 and 2 are fundamentally different seems unproductive:

1. From the door came a cry for help.
2. From the door there came a cry for help.
3. This is the door from which came a cry for help.

Because of case 3 I’ve reopened it, but the existing answers don’t seem to hit the nail on the head.  Too many words, too little meat.

Comment: Thank you for reopening. Hopefully some better answers will give us more _meat_. I am also _hungry_ to learn.